# Python stats.linregress syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate the regression of the `x` and `y` variables, `trace_no` and `twwt`, respectively.

The variable are `151 x 1` arrays.

The code is outputting a syntax error:

```
File "./seabed_dip_correction.py", line 32
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err, Syy/Sxx = stats.linregress(trace_no,twtt)
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I have tried switching the operator around i.e. `stats.linregress() = ...`but that doesn't work.

Here is my code, could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
data=np.genfromtxt('trace1_offset_gather.dat')
trace_no=data[:,[0]]
twtt=data[:,[1]]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err, Syy/Sxx = stats.linregress(trace_no,twtt)
```

Comment: What is that `Syy/Sxx` thing ?

Answer (score 3):

Your last variable, or rather pair of variables, is invalid.

```
Syy/Sxx
```

If that is supposed to be a single variable, know that you cannot have `/` in your variable name.

[Python identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

> Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following lexical definitions:

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

> Identifiers are unlimited in length. Case is significant.

If that is meant to be two variables, you cannot assign a value to an expression like this, it would be like saying

```
a/b = 2
```

That makes sense in mathematics, but not in Python, you must assign a value to a single variable, or in the case of unpacking `N` values to `N` variables.

**Edit**
The function [`scipy.stats.linregress`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) only returns 5 values, and they are

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```

Comment: I removed the "/" and ran the code with the line: slope, intercept, r, p, err, Sxx = stats.linregress(trace_no,twtt), however now it has a value error: "  File "./seabed_dip_correction.py", line 32, in <module>
    slope, intercept, r, p, err, Sxx = stats.linregress(trace_no,twtt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 3100, in linregress
    ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
ValueError: too many values to unpack". Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: @Kg123 That function only appears to return 5 values, you cannot return 5 values into 6 variables.

Comment: I did try with 5 values, but the error is the same whatever the number?

Comment: @Kg123 I assure you that the error will not occur if you use the correct number of arguments. What do you get if you `print(stats.linregress(trace_no, twtt))`?

Comment: I get the same error: ValueError: too many values to unpack